# reactjs handle click outside an element error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I'm trying to create a function that will detect any click outside of an element.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(e) {
      if (
        !(
          e.target.className.includes("ft-btn") ||
          e.target.parentElement.className.includes("ft-btn")
        )
      ) {
        setSortOpen(false);
        setFilterOpen(false);
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
  }, [sortOpen, filterOpen]);
```

The error says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null

The function works just fine when it only contains one of the conditions.

Is there any problem with my code? I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cases in which the parent element is `null`, and trying to access the `className` property of `null` would cause the error. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement):

> The Node.parentElement read-only property returns the DOM node's
> parent Element, or null if the node either has no parent, or its
> parent isn't a DOM Element.

You can [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to check if a node or it's parents match a specific selector:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleClickOutside(e) {
    if (!e.target.closest('.ft-btn')) { // check if element or parents has class
      setSortOpen(false);
      setFilterOpen(false);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
  
  // cleanup
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
  };
}, [sortOpen, filterOpen]);
```